# ess has disappeared from emacs

Tags: emacs, r

I frequently use emacs ess functions. Specifically, I use r-mode and run R in emacs. However, quite suddenly, emacs is no longer offering ess options. 
r-mode is no longer an option in emacs nor is R.

I tried purging ess and emacs (`aptitude --purge remove emacs ess`) and even removed my .emacs file and .emacs.d folder - to no avail.

I'm using Debian (Jessie). emacs23 was installed. In trying to get this to work, I installed emacs24, and then even xemacs (on the off chance). Still no success. I was having a problem with el-get -- so I purged and reinstalled related packages. Oddly enough, reinstalling `dictionaries-common` was some help there (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/295234/broken-emacs-installation)- but still no luck with emacs and ess.

There are no error messages installing, uninstalling, or reinstalling emacs, ess, or r.

How can I amend this?

Comment: What command do you run to get into the mode an are there any error messages? What OS is this? You said aptitude so I'm assuming some flavor of Debian, right? Which version of emacs?

Comment: I've addressed my problem in part by manually installing the ESS package from here http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Installation for now.

Comment: Cool, could you post your solution as an answer and accept it please?

Answer (score 0):

I've addressed my problem in part by manually installing the ESS package from [the project's installation page](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Installation) for now.